Google Drive API - limit API access to specific folder?
We are working for a client, who has given us permission to access the Google Drive API. Using this API, we need to create a folder structure in Google Drive and upload files into that structure. However, we are unable to access the directory through the API. Despite using the same service account, we can perform manual operations correctly, but we cannot do anything with the Google API, including retrieving folder information. Could it be that additional read/write permissions are required to access any folder using the Google API?

Contents of the Folders are displayed for all the folders except "Shared with me" folders. Is there any Extra settings Required for the Service account to access  "Shared with me"
